# Add Cache Factory to Controller

Tags: angularjs, ionic-framework

Need help to resolve caching in my Ionic App. To blog entries saved in storage to offline view.

I have example Controller with caching:

```
.controller('PostCtrl', function($scope, $stateParams, DataLoader, $ionicLoading, $rootScope, $sce, CacheFactory, $log, Bookmark, $timeout ) {

  if ( ! CacheFactory.get('postCache') ) {
    CacheFactory.createCache('postCache');
  }

  var postCache = CacheFactory.get( 'postCache' );

  $scope.itemID = $stateParams.postId;

  var singlePostApi = $rootScope.url + 'posts/' + $scope.itemID;

  $scope.loadPost = function() {

    // Fetch remote post

    $ionicLoading.show({
      noBackdrop: true
    });

    DataLoader.get( singlePostApi ).then(function(response) {

      $scope.post = response.data;

      $log.debug($scope.post);

      // Don't strip post html
      $scope.content = $sce.trustAsHtml(response.data.content.rendered);

      // $scope.comments = $scope.post._embedded['replies'][0];

      // add post to our cache
      postCache.put( response.data.id, response.data );

      $ionicLoading.hide();
    }, function(response) {
      $log.error('error', response);
      $ionicLoading.hide();
    });

  }

  if( !postCache.get( $scope.itemID ) ) {

    // Item is not in cache, go get it
    $scope.loadPost();

  } else {
    // Item exists, use cached item
    $scope.post = postCache.get( $scope.itemID );
    $scope.content = $sce.trustAsHtml( $scope.post.content.rendered );
    // $scope.comments = $scope.post._embedded['replies'][0];
  }

  // Sharing
  $scope.sharePost = function( link ){
    window.plugins.socialsharing.share('Check this post here: ', null, null, link);
  }

  // Bookmarking
  $scope.bookmarked = Bookmark.check( $scope.itemID );

  $scope.bookmarkItem = function( id ) {

    if( $scope.bookmarked ) {
      Bookmark.remove( id );
      $scope.bookmarked = false;
    } else {
      Bookmark.set( id );
      $scope.bookmarked = true;
    }
  }

  // Pull to refresh
  $scope.doRefresh = function() {

    $timeout( function() {

      $scope.loadPost();

      //Stop the ion-refresher from spinning
      $scope.$broadcast('scroll.refreshComplete');

    }, 1000);

  };

})
```

And have controller without cashing:

```
.controller('PostsCtrl', function( $scope, $http, DataLoader, $ionicLoading, $timeout, CacheFactory, $ionicSlideBoxDelegate, $rootScope, $log) {

  var postsApi = $rootScope.url + 'posts';

  $scope.moreItems = false;

  $scope.loadPosts = function() {

    $ionicLoading.show({
      noBackdrop: true
    });    

    // Get all of our posts
    DataLoader.get( postsApi ).then(function(response) {

      $scope.posts = response.data;

      $scope.moreItems = true;

      $log.log(postsApi, response.data);

      $ionicLoading.hide();
    }, function(response) {
      $ionicLoading.hide();      
      $log.log(postsApi, response.data);
    });

  }

  // Load posts on page load
  $scope.loadPosts();

  paged = 2;

  // Load more (infinite scroll)
  $scope.loadMore = function() {

    if( !$scope.moreItems ) {
      return;
    }

    var pg = paged++;

    $log.log('loadMore ' + pg );

    $timeout(function() {

      DataLoader.get( postsApi + '?page=' + pg ).then(function(response) {

        angular.forEach( response.data, function( value, key ) {
          $scope.posts.push(value);
        });

        if( response.data.length <= 0 ) {
          $scope.moreItems = false;
        }
      }, function(response) {
        $scope.moreItems = false;
        $log.error(response);
      });

      $scope.$broadcast('scroll.infiniteScrollComplete');
      $scope.$broadcast('scroll.resize');

    }, 1000);

  }

  $scope.moreDataExists = function() {
    return $scope.moreItems;
  }

  // Pull to refresh
  $scope.doRefresh = function() {

    $timeout( function() {

      $scope.loadPosts();

      //Stop the ion-refresher from spinning
      $scope.$broadcast('scroll.refreshComplete');

    }, 1000);

  };

})

.controller('CategoriesCtrl', function( $scope, $http, DataLoader, $ionicLoading, $timeout, CacheFactory, $ionicSlideBoxDelegate, $rootScope, $log ) {

  var categoriesApi = $rootScope.url + 'categories';

  $scope.moreItems = false;

  $scope.loadCategories = function() {

    $ionicLoading.show({
      noBackdrop: true
    });

    // Get all of our categories
    DataLoader.get( categoriesApi ).then(function(response) {

      $scope.categories = response.data;

      $scope.moreItems = true;

      $log.log(categoriesApi, response.data);

      $ionicLoading.hide();
    }, function(response) {
      $log.log(categoriesApi, response.data);
      $ionicLoading.hide();      
    });

  }

  // Load posts on page load
  $scope.loadCategories();

  paged = 2;

  // Load more (infinite scroll)
  $scope.loadMore = function() {

    if( !$scope.moreItems ) {
      return;
    }

    var pg = paged++;

    $log.log('loadMore ' + pg );

    $timeout(function() {

      DataLoader.get( categoriesApi + '?page=' + pg ).then(function(response) {

        angular.forEach( response.data, function( value, key ) {
          $scope.categories.push(value);
        });

        if( response.data.length <= 0 ) {
          $scope.moreItems = false;
        }
      }, function(response) {
        $scope.moreItems = false;
        $log.error(response);
      });

      $scope.$broadcast('scroll.infiniteScrollComplete');
      $scope.$broadcast('scroll.resize');

    }, 1000);

  }

  $scope.moreDataExists = function() {
    return $scope.moreItems;
  }

  // Pull to refresh
  $scope.doRefresh = function() {

    $timeout( function() {

      $scope.loadCategories();

      //Stop the ion-refresher from spinning
      $scope.$broadcast('scroll.refreshComplete');

    }, 1000);

  };

})
```

How to add caching to Posts controller?
This is caching Factories:

```
.factory('Bookmark', function( CacheFactory ) {

  if ( ! CacheFactory.get('bookmarkCache') ) {
    CacheFactory.createCache('bookmarkCache');
  }

  var bookmarkCache = CacheFactory.get( 'bookmarkCache' );

  return {
    set: function(id) {
      bookmarkCache.put( id, 'bookmarked' );
      window.plugins.toast.showShortCenter(
        "Bookmarked", function(a){}, function(b){}
      );
    },
    get: function(id) {
      bookmarkCache.get( id );
      console.log( id );
    },
    check: function(id) {
      var keys = bookmarkCache.keys();
      var index = keys.indexOf(id);
      if(index >= 0) {
        return true;
      } else {
        return false;
      }
    },
    remove: function(id) {
      bookmarkCache.remove(id);
      window.plugins.toast.showShortCenter(
        "Removed", function(a){}, function(b){}
      );      
    }
  }

})

.factory('$localstorage', ['$window', function($window) {
  return {
    set: function(key, value) {
      $window.localStorage[key] = value;
    },
    get: function(key, defaultValue) {
      return $window.localStorage[key] || defaultValue;
    },
    setObject: function(key, value) {
      $window.localStorage[key] = JSON.stringify(value);
    },
    getObject: function(key) {
      return JSON.parse($window.localStorage[key] || '{}');
    }
  }
}]);
```

Comment: Please read [ask]. Not at all clear what your specific problem is

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of `CacheFactory` use `$cacheFactory`.
Documentation [here](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$cacheFactory)